# Unable to open openfileDialog in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to use openfiledialog to upload file,but when I write following code Security exception is fired that is "Dialogs must be user-initiated."

```
btn_click()
{
  OpenFileDialog fileDialog=new OpenFileDialog();            
  fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
  fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
  bool? retval = fileDialog.ShowDialog();   
  if (fileDialog.ShowDialog()==false){ 
    Stream strm = fileDialog.File.OpenRead();
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[strm.Length];
    strm.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)strm.Length);
    strm.Dispose();
    strm.Close();
    Uploadfile file=new Uploadfile(); 
    file.FileName = fileDialog.File.Name;
    file.File = Buffer; 
    po.fileUploadAsync(file);
  }
```

Comment: Anil - please roll back your edit to the second version and **add** your code to the question rather than replacing the original text.

Answer (score 1):

As the exception you're getting states the open file dialog can only be activated from a user initiated action when the application is run in the browser and with restricted trust.

What are you trying to achieve?

The simplest solution is to add a button to your UI that allows the user to control when this process happens.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have created file upload user control in silverlight and on browse button click I write above code. But unable to open dialog.

Comment: private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
OpenFileDialog fileDialog=new OpenFileDialog();            
fileDialog.Multiselect = false; fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
bool? dialogresult = fileDialog.ShowDialog();       
if (fileDialog.ShowDialog()==false){
Stream strm = fileDialog.File.OpenRead();
byte[] Buffer = new byte[strm.Length];
strm.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)strm.Length);
strm.Dispose();strm.Close();Uploadfile file=new Uploadfile();
file.FileName = fileDialog.File.Name;file.File = Buffer;
po.fileUploadAsync(file);
}

Comment: @Anil - please edit this into your question where it can be properly formatted.

Comment: this is browse btn code. I'm getting exception on                bool? dialogresult = fileDialog.ShowDialog(); as "Dialogs must be user-initiated." So What should I write to avoid exception.

Comment: @Anil - please edit both comments into your question - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5179431/edit - where they'll be formatted so that they're readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){ 

   using (StreamReader reader = dlg.SelectedFile.OpenText())   
     // Store file content in 'text' variable      
  string text = reader.ReadToEnd();   
 }

}
```